# CakePHP 3 join on a secondary key using ORM

Tags: cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3.5.13 - working with a legacy database. I have a table called `substances` where the primary key is `id`. There is also another column in this table called `app_id`.

The majority of tables in the application have a foreign key which means they can be joined to `substances.id`. There is one table called `article_95` which has a field `article_95.app_id` and therefore the join must be made to `substances.app_id` (not `substances.id` - there is no reference to that field inside the `article_95` table at all).

The application performs a search based on up to 11 inputs. I'm using the ORM to dynamically build the query object before executing it.

I begin my query like this:

```
$query = $Substances->find()->select(['id' => 'Substances.id'])->distinct();
```

Then if I wanted to do something where the join maps to `substances.id`, I'm doing it like this:

```
// Search by CAS Number
if ($this->request->getData('cas_number')) {
    $cas_number = $this->request->getData('cas_number');
    $query = $query->matching('Cas', function ($q) use ($cas_number) {
        return $q->where([
            'Cas.value LIKE' => '%'.$cas_number.'%'
        ]);
    });
}
```

So far so good. If I output the SQL string it looks like this:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT Substances.id AS `id` FROM substances Substances INNER JOIN cas_substances CasSubstances ON Substances.id = (CasSubstances.substance_id) INNER JOIN cas Cas ON (Cas.value like :c0 AND Cas.id = (CasSubstances.cas_id))'
```

My problem comes with how to manipulate the query object when it comes to my `article_95` table, because it's trying to join on `substances.id` when I need it to join on `substances.app_id`.

I have the following in my `Table` classes. Please note the line `$this->setPrimaryKey('tbl_id');` - this is because I'm using a legacy/old database and the primary key of the `article_95` table is actually `tbl_id` not `id`. However this is relatively insignificant because the join should be based on `app_id` which exists in both tables.

```
// src/Model/Table/SubstancesTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setTable('substances');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    $this->hasMany('Article95s', [
        'foreignKey' => 'app_id'
    ]);
    // ...
}


// src/Model/Table/Article95sTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setTable('article_95');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('tbl_id');

    $this->belongsTo('Substances', [
        'foreignKey' => 'app_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

If I try and do a search which include an Article 95 value the SQL string becomes like this:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT Substances.id AS `id` FROM substances Substances INNER JOIN cas_substances CasSubstances ON Substances.id = (CasSubstances.substance_id) INNER JOIN cas Cas ON (Cas.value like :c0 AND Cas.id = (CasSubstances.cas_id)) INNER JOIN article_95 Article95s ON (Article95s.entity_name like :c1 AND Substances.id = (Article95s.app_id))'
```

The problem with this is the part of the SQL string which reads **`Substances.id = (Article95s.app_id))`**. I need that to be `Substances.app_id = (Article95s.app_id))` but I don't know how to write this with the ORM syntax.

It's also important that the rest of the joins (e.g. CAS Number shown previously) remain joined on `substances.id`.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [**manual**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together) explain it all

### belongsTo

> **bindingKey**: The name of the column in the **other table**, that will be used for matching the foreignKey. If not specified, the primary key (for example the id column of the Users table) will be used.

```
$this->belongsTo('Substances', [
    'foreignKey' => 'app_id',
    'bindingKey' => 'app_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

### hasMany

> **bindingKey**: The name of the column in the **current table**, that will be used for matching the foreignKey. If not specified, the primary key (for example the id column of the Articles table) will be used.

```
$this->hasMany('Article95s', [
    'foreignKey' => 'app_id',
    'bindingKey' => 'app_id',
]);
```